# SQL query to add a column with the specific count

Tags: sql, count, group-by, left-join

I have the following table Tble :

```
Name  |  Level
--------------
n1    |  L1
n1    |  L2
n2    |  L1
n2    |  L3
n3    |  L1
n4    |  L3
```

How can I write a SQL query to output like that ?

```
Name  |  Level  |  CountOfDifferentLevelsForName
-------------------------------------------
n1    |  L1     |  2
n1    |  L2     |  2
n2    |  L1     |  2
n2    |  L3     |  2
n3    |  L1     |  1
n4    |  L3     |  1
```

i.e. for example, n1 has two levels L1 and L2

I tried to do :
SELECT Name, count(*) FROM Tble GROUP BY Name

but as soon as I want to see the Level also... it messes up the counts, or does not show all the rows

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

...and without using a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT tb1.Name, tb1.Level, count(*) c
FROM Tble tb1
JOIN Tble tb2 ON tb1.Name = tb2.Name
GROUP BY tb1.Name, tb1.Level
```

Make sure the column used in the join (`Name`) is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
select name,lvl,count(*) over (partition by name) as tot_cnt from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to achieve tour desired result. One of them is by joining on a subquery which separately gets the number of records for every Name and the result of the subquery is then joined back on the table itself.

```
SELECT  a.name, a.Level,
        b.TotalCount
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  Name, Count(*) TotalCount
            FROM    TableName
            GROUp   BY Name
        ) b ON a.Name = b.Name
```

For faster performance, you should define an `INDEX` on column `Name`.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1271/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ NAME ║ LEVEL ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ n1   ║ L1    ║          2 ║
║ n1   ║ L2    ║          2 ║
║ n2   ║ L1    ║          2 ║
║ n2   ║ L3    ║          2 ║
║ n3   ║ L1    ║          1 ║
║ n4   ║ L3    ║          1 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

*The Name which has 1 level and that level is L1 (i.e n3)*

query:

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1 AND
        MAX(Level) = 'L1'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1271/22)

*The Name which has 2 levels and these levels are L1 and L3 (i.e. n2)*

query:

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2 AND
        SUM(CASE WHEN Level IN ('L1', 'L3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1271/23)

Comment: Thank you JW... love the SQLFiddle ;)

Comment: Thanks a million! That is exactly what I was hoping for... struggled lots of time on that today.